# How to update a particular row DataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, row

In data table i want to update each row dynamically.

I am using `p:poll` here for auto updating (For keeping dataTable uptodate).
My main aim is to update the data (records) dynamically as it changes

I have tried this.

```
<p:column headerText="Vehicle Info" width="65" id="vehicleInfo">
           <h:outputText id="txt_count"
                         value="count #{vehicleController.count}"/>
</p:column>
```

How can i achieve it?

Comment: What's the problem with updating the whole datatable? Normally it's no big problem.

Comment: You're contradicting yourself with "update a particular row", "update each row" and "the data (records)". What exactly is the concrete functional requirement?

Comment: Where are you editing your data?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try selector in example: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectors.jsf